# How can lemmatize arabic text using its POS tags?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, arabic, lemmatization

when I use lemmatize for arabic the word dosn't change how can lemmatize arabic text using its **POS** tags?

[the output I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWZVp.png)

Comment: Wordnet lemmatizer does English only.  If you want to stick with nltk there is an arabic [stemming package](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html) available but if you want true lemmatization for arabic you might have to look elsewhere.

Comment: but When I using stemming for Arabic sometimes it returns meaningless words If I choose to do stemming for the file do you think it will affect  badly on the results   or can I get acceptable results I want to get the frequency of words in txt document I want to simplify words that related to each other to one word like "قاتل , يقتلون , قاتلون,  قاتل"  I want them to return the same word whatever it is right or wrong

Comment: @noura, take a few minutes to search in the nltk book (or source code) and find out how stemming and lemmatization algorithms work. Or take one minute to think about it. You can't use an English lemmatizer on Arabic, no matter how much you would like to have lemmatization available for your project.

Comment: @alexis I tried to use stemming but it still give meaningless words it remove some letters from the root of the word and I want the root at least